Google Chrome Devtools search for string shows 15 matches, only highlights 2
Chrome Devtools will report the number of matches of a string I search, but won't actually show me the elements. It tells me I have 15 matches for my search and only highlights two of them.
Searching for answers on this has turned up nothing except a million questions about "CSS selectors" which is not my issue as I'm searching a plain string.
I have a website open in Chrome v124, F12 to open Devtools, Ctrl-F to search for a string (in this case, I searched for 'offline' minus the single quotes).
It tells me I have 15 matches and highlights the first match. I am only able to cycle through the first two matches with the up/down arrows.
After that, the highlighter doesn't move, and cycling through the matches with the arrows does nothing but change the match number.
Is this intended behaviour? If so, why? If not, how do I fix this?
EXAMPLE TO REPRODUCE:

Visit the Twitch link https://www.twitch.tv/hasanabi
Open devtools and Ctrl-F to search for the string "offline" (minus quotes)
Out of 29 matches, it will stop cycling after number 18

This streamer's twitch link was not streaming when I searched. When I search a link of a streamer who is online and streaming, I get 15 matches and it stops cycling after number 2.

You’d need to ask them “why”. Without a concrete example it’s difficult to guess. It’s almost always hidden or off-screen text when it’s happened to me.

@DaveNewton Thanks for the comment, I edited my question to include an example

Sounds like a bug, which I can't reproduce in Chrome 125.
